# exiting python with hanged thread

Tags: python

When you import and use package, this package can run non daemon threads. Until these threads are finished, python cannot exit properly (like with sys.exit(0)). For example imagine that thread t is from some package. When unhandled exception occurs in the main thread, you want to terminate. But this won't exit immediately, it will wait 60s till the thread terminates.

```
import time, threading

def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(60,))
    t.start()

    a = 5 / 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except:
        sys.exit(1)
```

So I came up with 2 things. Replace sys.exit(1) with os._exit(1) or enumerate all threads and make them daemon. Both of them seems to work, but what do you thing is better? os._exit won't flush stdio buffers but setting daemon attribute to threads seems like a hack and maybe it's not guaranteed to work all the time.

```
import time, threading

def main():
    t = thread.Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(60,))
    t.start()

    a = 5 / 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except:
        for t in threading.enumerate():
            if not t.daemon and t.name != "MainThread":
                t._daemonic = True

        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: A bit of a kludgy way to deal with this is to monkey patch.

Comment: The proper solution is to notify threads when you want to quit, force them to quit and `join` them. This can be done by polling some global flag in each thread.

Comment: yup, but if threads are created internally by some pip package function I am out of luck. Monkey patching that would run all the threads as daemon would probably work in my case.

Comment: @Caldur Both your ideas may lead to an unpredictable behaviour (including inconsistency beyond repair, if for example the package uses I/O in threads). In order to be 100% sure that it doesn't break anything you would have to know the code of the package in great details. Perhaps it would be easier to rewrite the package? Anyway it seems that you are using wrong tool for the job. Isn't the timeout configurable?